# How to access variable of an Outer class in the inner class in c#

Tags: c#

i have two class i need to declare a variable common to both the classes..

In case of Nested classes i need to access the Outer class variable in the inner class

please give me a better way to do this in c#.

Sample code

```
 Class A
   {
     int a;
     Class B
        {
               // Need to access " a" here
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: CAn you post a short code sample so we can have a better idea of what you are doing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First suggestion is to pass a reference to the Outer class to the Inner class on construction, so Inner class that then reference Outer class properties.

Comment: It's quite self explanatory, really. Give it a try first.

Answer (score 5):

```
public Class Class_A
{
    int a;

    public Class Class_B
    {
        Class_A instance;

        public Class_B(Class_A a_instance)
        {
            instance = a_instance;
        }

        void SomeMethod()
        {
            int someNumber = this.instance.a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: without creating an instance ?

Comment: How would I call Class_B and pass in Class_A then?

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you probably need to pass a as a parameter to B in it's constructor - there's not way to access it otherwise.  Having this as a 'child' class may not be a great design, however, but there's not enough information to really know either way.