# In a private class : access to a member of the "outer class"?

Tags: c#

Here is my code (just a snippet to expose the problem) :

```
public class A
{
    class B
    {
        //private class
    }

    public int nb;
}
```

Im tired but why can't I access to "nb" in my private class ?

Comment: Where and how are you trying to access nb?

Comment: where the "private class" comment is writen, I can't access to nb

Comment: Please add the code. this way we are shooting in the dark.

Comment: I just can't do something like "int nb2 = nb;" in the private class

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access variable of an Outer class in the inner class in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139570/how-to-access-variable-of-an-outer-class-in-the-inner-class-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're gonna need an instance of A in order to access the instance member `nb`:

```
public class A
{
    class B
    {
        public B()
        {
            A a = new A();
            int nb = a.nb;
        }
    }

    public int nb;
}
```

Comment: Maybe better make it `internal`?

Comment: @abatishchev, make internal what? The nested class? Why? What if this class wasn't intended to be used outside of A? Making it a nested private class makes sense.

Comment: I mean `public int nb` -> `internal int nb`

Comment: Ok, get the solution even if that kinda surprise me ! about making it internal, I won't use B outside of A

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in java but not in C#.

You need to pass an instance of `A` to `B`.

Answer (score 2):

In C# an 'outer' class is just a 'namespace' to the inner class. So the outer class is not being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an instance of `A` to `B`, like so:

```
public class A
{
    class B
    {
        private A _outerClass;
        public B(A outerClass)
        {
            _outerClass = outerClass;
            // Then you can access nb thus:
            _outerClass.nb;
        }

    }

    public int nb;
}
```